# The minimal transitive model of $\sf ZF$ as an arbiter on Platonic truths of independent statements of $\sf ZF$?

Tags: set-theory, philosophy

Statements in the language of set theory that are independent of $\sf ZF$, and that are within the consistency level of $\sf ZF$, like $\sf AC$, $\sf CH$ and $\sf GCH$, etc... These need a certain truth criterion to decide on whether they are true or not in let's say ***the*** Platonic world of sets, which we would take it to be a single world (not a multiverse).

Why we don't take the decision made by the minimal transitive model of $\sf ZF$ on those statements to be that criterion?

I'm asking about the mathematical side of this question, I mean in what sense this arbiter is poor or otherwise strong? Are there known interesting independent statements that it cannot decide on?

Comment: Do you advocate the minimal transitive model of $\sf ZF$ viz. your title or of $\sf ZFC$ viz. your body?

Comment: @J.G., Thank you. I've correct it.

Comment: @J.G. It's actually a model of ZFC, since it has to be $L_\alpha$ for the least possible $\alpha$.

Answer (score 3):

Based on your comments, it sounds like you want to focus on questions either answer to which adds no consistency strength to $\mathsf{ZF}$, and for such questions set a "default" truth value based on $L_\alpha$. There are various possible responses, but one I think is important to give is that **the interaction between such "simple" questions and high-consistency-strength principles is very complicated in general**.

For example, we're used to the idea that large cardinals - even *very* large cardinals - don't impact the continuum function. But that takes serious work; I don't believe that there is a trivial argument that (for example) if the existence of a supercompact cardinal is consistent with $\mathsf{ZFC}$ then it is consistent with $\mathsf{ZFC+GCH}$. Certainly I'm not comfortable turning to $L_\alpha$ for answers to "natural combinatorial questions" (even assuming we can somehow dodge those secretly referring to $L$ itself) and blithely assuming that the answers so provided do not impinge on other aspects of the set-theoretic universe that are important to me.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with the minimal transitive model is that it's $L_\alpha$ for some countable ordinal $\alpha$.

This model is very poor in large cardinals, indeed it has none, and if we want to think about set theoretic background for forcing, and we want to use countable transitive models for that, then this is again not a suitable choice, since it will not have any transitive models of $\sf ZFC$ inside of it.

One can argue that adopting $V=L$ + "No transitive models of $\sf ZFC$" will answer the vast majority of our reasonably independent questions, like $\sf GCH$, like the existence (or rather lack thereof) of large cardinals, etc. But it does so in an incredibly poor and boring way.

Besides, unlike with the case of $\sf PA$, where "the standard model" is somehow tangible and understood, this $L_\alpha$ is still fairly abstract and $\alpha$ is incomprehensibly large as far as countable ordinals go. After all, it will know all the reasonable things you can do with Turing machines, their oracles, and so on. So it is necessarily closed under all the standard recursive hierarchies and all that.

Comment: @user14111: So, you don't want to have a universe in which all sets of reals are Lebesgue measurable?

Comment: @AsafKaragila, hmmm..! I actually wanted it to be an arbiter on weak independent statements and not on questions with an option that is of  consistency strength higher than $\sf ZF$, so questions about large cardinals, existence models of $\sf ZF$ etc... are all beyond this. I mean as far as those weak independent statements, does it serve as a good arbiter?

Comment: @Zuhair: Again, what is "good"? It's a subjective measure. Is $V=L$ a statement that we want to have as "canonical truth" in mathematics, or is it not? To some extent, that statement on its own already decides most "reasonable statements" in a way. So you can view it as a certain degree of a completion. But again, is it a good canonical choice? It does affect those "other things" as well, which is something you need to consider, even if you didn't intend for it.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, I don't think AD is true, anyhow if it is seen as true, then one needs to choose another criterion for truth, I think this might be what the minimal $L_\alpha(\mathbb R)$ such that $L_\alpha(\mathbb R) \models \sf ZF + AD$, say.

Comment: @Zuhair: So, the real arbiter here is whoever is choosing the model. That's my point, the least transitive model has properties most people in set theory would feel are inadequate and do not reflect what we want to have (for example, large cardinals, or at least the existence of transitive models for forcing and the generic multiverse).